# Error (Cannot get property "subscribe" of undefined) in react-redux trySubscribe with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My React won't load on Internet Explorer 10 (Working correctly with Chrome and FF).

I'm getting error :

```
TypeError: Cannot get property "subscribe" of undefined 
at trySubscribe
at componentDidMount 
at notifyAll 
at close 
at closeAll 
at perform 
at perform 
at perform 
at m 
at close
```

(translated)

the trySubscribe function is in react-redux ( src/components/connect.js ):

```
trySubscribe() {
        if (shouldSubscribe && !this.unsubscribe) {
          this.unsubscribe = this.store.subscribe(this.handleChange.bind(this))
          this.handleChange()
        }
      }
```

So it seems that this.store is undefined but I don't know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

I was using a container component extending another container component, and both of them where decorated with `@connect` !

So I was trying to `@connect` a component which was not part of the components tree !

After removing `@connect` from superclass, problem solved !
(Actually I completely removed the superclass (not used anymore) and extended directly `Component`).